# Finite field with infinitesimals / nonstandard analysis over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, nonstandard-analysis, nonstandard-models

I have two questions, which are really the same question phrased in two ways:

- Has there been any research on adjoining infinitesimal elements to finite fields?
- Has anyone considered extensions to finite fields, which would stand in relation to finite fields as e.g. the hyperreal numbers stand in relation to the real numbers in nonstandard analysis?

(Note: I found a thing called "hyperfinite sets", but one of these appears to be a set that is finite in a nonstandard model, and I don't think that's quite the same thing since it internally "thinks" it's finite; whereas the fields I have in mind would know internally that they have infinitesimals.)

The background is as follows.  Given $\mathbb R$ we can, using compactness, obtain a model containing an **infinitesimal element** $\varepsilon$, namely one that is greater than zero but smaller than any strictly positive element in $\mathbb R$.  We can also concretely build such a model using an ultrafilter construction over a non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\mathbb N$.  An example of an infinitesimal would be $(1/n \mid n\in\mathbb N)_{\mathcal U}$, the equivalence class of a sequence tending to $0$.  This much is well-known.

It seems to me plausible that we might carry out a similar ultrafilter construction over a finite field, and this too would contain infinitesimal elements.  For example (sketch construction):
$$
(0,0,0,\dots)_{\mathcal U} < (1,0,1,0,1,\dots)_{\mathcal U} < (1,1,1,1,\dots)_{\mathcal U}.
$$
Has a construction in this spirit been studied, and if so can anyone provide references?

Thank you.

Comment: The ultrapower of a finite field $F=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ is just the finite field itself: for any sequence of elements $f\in F^\mathbb{N}$, one of the sets $\{i: f(i)=a_1\},...,\{i: f(i)=a_n\}$ will be in the ultrafilter, so $f/\mathcal{U}$ will be equal to some $a_i$('s canonical image in the ultrapower). Also, finite fields aren't ordered, so I don't know how to interpret the "<" in your sketch, but per the above that's a side point.

Comment: Like Noah Schweber says, nonstandard extensions don't do anything with finite sets so you get nothing interesting. The only interesting thing you could do is choose an infinite prime hypernatural $\omega$ and consider say $\mathbb F_\omega$.

Comment: Regarding "the fields I have in mind would know internally that they have infinitesimals", this isn't even how hyperreals work. Hyperreals, internally, are **exactly** the same as the reals (this being the transfer principle) and do not have infinitesimals in the sense that they are a hypernatural-Archimedean field. It is only *relative* to the standard reals and naturals that hyperreals contain infinitesimals, but then you are no longer taking a purely "internal" viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers.  This is all very clear.

Comment: There is a useful version of differentiation of, say, polynomials over finite fields, but it does not involve infinitesimals.  One simply defines the derivative of $x^n$ to be $nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finite fields have no ordering: no field with positive characteristic can be made into an ordered field.  So your premise of adjoining an element "greater than zero but smaller than any strictly positive element" doesn't make sense with finite fields.

At the same time, you can adjoin to *any* field $K$ an element $\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon \not= 0$ and $\varepsilon^2 = 0$ by using $K[x]/(x^2)$. There $x \bmod x^2$ has the desired property, but this is certainly not a field anymore. (Look up the term "dual numbers".) More generally, by using $K[x]/(x^m)$ you have adjoined to $K$ a nonzero element $\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon^m  = 0$ and no smaller power of $\varepsilon$ vanishes.